# issue trying to use pecl to install mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb, pecl

I tried installing PHP MongoDB Extension with "pecl install mongodb" and i got an error message saying
"No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb"

i have tried doing it manually by going to the official pecl website: https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb then click on the DLL link for your version of choice.
On next page scroll down and download the one matching your PHP version.
Then you should extract the zip file and copy the php_mongodb.dll to your php/ext dir. Then open your php.ini and add the following line:extension=php_mongodb.dll

This didn't work because i could not find the DLl version required
the latest version with DLL is 1.13.0 but I'm required to use version 1.16.1 which has no DLl

how else can i solve this issue please

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Composer? Why not install the extension through PECL?

Comment: Also, https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases contains a lot of more current releases with DLL files

Comment: **How** did you try that? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: i tried using PECL to install the extension but i got an error message saying "No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb".  I also tried using composer to install it and i got an error message saying "Cannot use mongodb/mongodb's latest version 1.16.0 as it requires ext-mongodb ^1.16.0 which is missing from your platform" How else can i  install the Mongodb driver successfully

Comment: with composer i did "composer require mongodb/mongodb" and with PECL i did "Pecl install monogodb

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it**, not to the comment section

Comment: @Hassanoladipupo I have exactly the same problem. If I visit PECL website, the latest version of the DLL is 1.13.0, however, I need the last one (1.16.2). Did you find any solutions?